# I open 5 different forms via Form1 but i can't save all positions

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, position

I have a project and I'm locked. I open different forms on Form1 you see below in the code. I did this with "notifyIcon". Instead of opening 5 different forms, I am bringing one by changing the form. I have 5 forms on my screen. But my problem is; I can save the locations of the forms. Technically they all come from the same form, so they all start from the same position. Do you have a recommendation?

**Edit :
A new idea came to mind. but I need your help again. when I close the form, I can save the form's position to a TxT file and manually start the positions with the positions from TxT when the forms are opened.**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        string dosyaYolu = @"D:\color\colors.txt";
        string[] satirlar = File.ReadAllLines(dosyaYolu);
    }

    private void tCKToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dosyaYolu = @"D:\color\colors.txt";
        string[] satirlar = File.ReadAllLines(dosyaYolu);

        string tckRenk = satirlar[0];
        Color tckColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(tckRenk);

        Form2 tckForm = new Form2();
        tckForm.Opacity = .50;
        tckForm.TopMost = true;
        tckForm.BackColor = tckColor;
        tckForm.LabelText = "TCK";
        tckForm.Show();

    }

    private void aDAToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dosyaYolu = @"D:\color\colors.txt";
        string[] satirlar = File.ReadAllLines(dosyaYolu);

        string adaRenk = satirlar[1];
        Color adaColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(adaRenk);

        Form2 adaForm = new Form2();
        adaForm.Opacity = .50;
        adaForm.TopMost = true;            
        adaForm.BackColor = adaColor;
        adaForm.LabelText = "ADA";
        adaForm.Show();

    }
```

Comment: Do not call the constructor each time you open form  Instead make child forms invisible (instead of closing) so when they open again they stay at there old position.  See my two form project : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: If you mean : Open each at a different position: Keep track of the forms, e.g. in a List<Form2> and use the count or index to decide on the position.  If you mean: Restore to the same positiom youi will need to save to some persistent storage..

Comment: I mean, when i open 3 forms on Form1 with notifyIcon and move forms, when i close forms or restart computer, forms should be same position.

Comment: Consider persisting the info of where those forms where on closing and between the constructor call and de Show/ShowDialog set its form location based on the persisted info.

Comment: BTW: Different questions like 'how to persist application data' should make different answers to avoid overly broad questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can set From Location

```
    Form frm2 = new Form();
    frm2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    frm2.Left = 500;
    frm2.Top = 500;
    frm2.Show();
```

Comment: If i set like this, other forms open Left=500, Top=500. I want this, i open 3 diffrent windows, first is left second is middle and third is right. when i close all and open again, they stay left mid and right. forms are draggable

Comment: You can keep their position in a variable. or hide forms instead of close

Comment: I cant hide, couse if i restart pc they should be same position. i think this, can i use "Move Event"? how can i save positions with move event?

Comment: get position of any forms after Moved and save this position on setting text file. after restrat your program read file and set position of forms.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class extensions
{
    public static void SaveFormSizeAndLocation(this Form form)
    {
        try
        {
            using (RegistryKey key = Application.UserAppDataRegistry.CreateSubKey(form.Name))
            {
                if (key != null)
                {
                    if (form.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
                    {
                        key.SetValue("Left", form.Left);
                        key.SetValue("Top", form.Top);
                        key.SetValue("Width", form.Width);
                        key.SetValue("Height", form.Height);
                    }
                    if (form.ShowInTaskbar)
                    {
                        string windowState = Enum.GetName(typeof(FormWindowState), form.WindowState);
                        key.SetValue("WindowState", form.WindowState);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Party on, Garth!
        }
    }
    public static void LoadFormSizeAndLocation(this Form form)
    {
        try
        {
            using (RegistryKey key = Application.UserAppDataRegistry.OpenSubKey(form.Name))
            {
                if (key != null)
                {
                    form.Left = (int)key.GetValue("Left", form.Left);
                    form.Top = (int)key.GetValue("Top", form.Top);
                    form.Width = (int)key.GetValue("Width", form.Width);
                    form.Height = (int)key.GetValue("Height", form.Height);
                    // Move window into visible screen bounds if outside screen bounds (prevent off-screen hidden windows)
                    Rectangle screenRect = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen;
                    if (form.Left < screenRect.Left)
                        form.Left = screenRect.Left;
                    if (form.Top < screenRect.Top)
                        form.Top = screenRect.Top;
                    if (form.Right > screenRect.Right)
                        form.Left = screenRect.Right - form.Width;
                    if (form.Bottom > screenRect.Bottom)
                        form.Top = screenRect.Bottom - form.Height;
                    if (form.ShowInTaskbar)
                    {
                        string windowState = Enum.GetName(typeof(FormWindowState), form.WindowState);
                        windowState = key.GetValue("WindowState", windowState).ToString();
                        form.WindowState = (FormWindowState)Enum.Parse(typeof(FormWindowState), windowState);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Party on, Wayne!
        }
    }
}
```

Use this extension methods and call it on form shown, form Closing & form Move events

For Complete Working Sample

```
  public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    private int count = 1;
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Move(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SaveFormSizeAndLocation();
    }

    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        Text = Name;
        base.OnShown(e);
        this.LoadFormSizeAndLocation();
        this.Move += Form2_Move;
    }

    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
        this.SaveFormSizeAndLocation();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var frm = new Form3();
        frm.Name = "inner" + count.ToString();
        frm.Show();
        count++;
    }
}
```